# Custom Category Image Attribute Preview

Tags: magento-1.9, category-attribute, image-preview

I've created a custom image attribute for the category. The image will be saved in `media/catalog/category/example` location.

When I upload the image, preview showing as a broken image even though image exists in that location.

```
$installer->addAttribute($entity, 'g_main_image', array(
    'input'=>'image',
    'type'=>'varchar',
    'label'=>'Gallery Main Image',
    'required'=>false,
    'visible'=>true,
    'user_defined'=>true,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
));
```

Image preview showing `http://localhost/dev/media/catalog/category/audi.jpg` but the actual image is in

```
http://localhost/dev/media/catalog/category/gallery/audi.jpg
```

Comment: check the image url in backend that tried to preview.and update with your question.

Comment: Added the url for reference.

Comment: why dont you use magento category image attribute?

Comment: I am using category image for other purposes.

Comment: just post the code you used for category image saving.

Comment: I'm not using any code to save it. Its an Magento's image attribute

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19605/discussion-between-manik-and-blakcaps).

Answer (score 0):

Change permission to your `media/category` to 755.

**or**

You are saving the image to a directory and not correctly reference it in the table, so check your custom attribute value.

Comment: How changing file permission would help?Image is displaying correctly on the frontend. Only image preview  in the backend is not working.I suppose this is something to do with the code.

Comment: oh ok sorry i misunderstood, i'll come up with solution.

Comment: check the url in backend it tries to fetch.and post it.

Comment: save image value in db like gallery/{imagename.jpg} and check.plz add gallery before imagename in db table before save.